# Service Manager not populating ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

hello developer right now I learn mvvm. I want to populate the data in my viewModel and I create my service as a singleton. but somehow it didn't work, in my uilabel. instead my uilabel text is disappear, I didn't know if this my setup viewModel is wrong or not. should I separate the model, since I have two model object inside my view model. here I show you my code.

```
class ProfileViewModel {

    private var infos: InfoResult?
    private var cities = [City]()
    private var religions = [Religion]()

    private let services: BasicInfoServices

    var profileID: String {
        return infos?.id ?? ""
    }

    var imageURL: String {
        let imageUrl = infos?.docAwsUrl ?? ""
        return imageUrl
    }

    var fullName: String {
        return infos?.fullName ?? ""
    }

    var phoneNumber: String {
        return infos?.phoneNumber ?? ""
    }

    var email: String {
        return infos?.email ?? ""
    }

    var cityOfBirth: String {
        var cityName = ""
        cities.forEach { city in
            if infos?.pobId == city.id {
                cityName = city.name ?? ""
            }
        }
        return cityName
    }

    var dateOfBirth: String {
        return infos?.dob ?? ""
    }

    var religion: String {
        var religionName = ""
        religions.forEach { religion in
            if infos?.religionId == religion.id {
                religionName = religion.name
            }
        }
        return religionName
    }

    init(services: BasicInfoServices) {
        self.services = services
        populateProfile()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewModel {

    func populateProfile() {
        // Basic Info
        self.services.getBasicInfo { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let profile):
                self?.infos = profile
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

        // City
        self.services.getCity { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let cities):
                self?.cities = cities
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

        // Religion
        self.services.getReligion { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let religions):
                self?.religions = religions
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

// I initialise it in viewController
    var viewModel: ProfileViewModel!
    var services = BasicInfoServices()

// than I test it in viewDidLoad
    viewModel = ProfileViewModel(services: services)
    profileLbl.text = viewModel.fullName // when set this my profileLbl place holder disappear.
    profileImage.getUserImage(urlString: viewModel.imageURL)
```

Comment: please check `populateProfile` `self?.infos = profile` line called or not called? because if it is not called your `info` is `nil` and your viewModel's `fullName` is basically returns `info?.fullname` but if your `info` is `nil` it returns `""` (empty string) so `profileLbl.text = viewModel.fullName` this removes your label's placeholder because `viewModel.fullName` is empty string. I think you should check `getBasicInfo` function.

Comment: yes it is being called @emrcftci :)

Comment: then could you please check the `profile` which we took in `getBasicInfo`'s `success` case? Maybe `profile`'s `fullName` is `nil`.

Comment: there are no placeholders in UILabels. if the text changes, then that means you somehow set a text. Considering your code, that can happen if data is nil. because of ?? ""

Comment: I think I know what happen, I try to debug from the top. I print it and it's nil. so the service is not yet being called before that that's why my profileLbl is nil @emrcftci . but know I don't know how to execute services first in viewModel :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) At this line, you make API requests so this is an async process**

`viewModel = ProfileViewModel(services: services)`

**2) Without waiting for the success response, you try to use response data in next line**

`profileLbl.text = viewModel.fullName`

## Tips for you

1) You should use closures to detect API responses.

```
class ProfileViewModel {

    var info: InfoResult?
    private let services: BasicInfoServices

    init(services: BasicInfoServices) {
        self.services = services
    }

    func loadData(success: (()->()), failure: ((String)->())){
        self.services.getBasicInfo { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let infoResult):
                self?.info = infoResult
                success()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                failure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2) After receiving data, you can show this on the view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel = ProfileViewModel(services: BasicInfoServices())

    @IBOutlet weak var lblProfileID:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFullName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblPhoneNumber:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblEmail:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDataOfBirth:UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.viewModel.loadData(success: {
            self.populateUserData()
        }, failure: { errorString in
            print(errorString)
        })

    }

    func populateUserData(){

        self.lblProfileID.text = self.viewModel.info?.id
        self.lblFullName.text = self.viewModel.info?.fullName
        self.lblPhoneNumber.text = self.viewModel.info?.phoneNumber
        self.lblEmail.text = self.viewModel.info?.email
        self.lblDataOfBirth.text = self.viewModel.info?.dob

    }

}
```

Comment: you right, I just found out. but how can I wait the response in viewModel? I hear the viewModel should never add UIKit in it. @ThilinaChaminHewagama

Comment: @ferryawijayanto, check my answer now.

Comment: thank you @ThilinaChaminHewagama it work like a charm, thank you for your guidance I learn so much from you :)